# Why is it printing semi colon(;)?

Tags: c

The below program when executed is printing ';' as output. I am not understanding why. When I am changing the value of 'c' and 'i', it is sometimes adding those two and sometimes printing symbols like '=' and ';'

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c='1';
    int i=10;
    printf("%c", c|i);
}
```

Comment: What do you not understand? It's the result of a bitwise OR. What is your expected output and why?

Comment: You are doing Or bitwise operation on Character `1` which has some value and 10. It is a new number, which is the ascii value of ; I guess.

Comment: Ascii value of '1' is 49 and value in 1 is 10, you are performing or operation, then it become 59 and you are printing character, in the ascii table 59 is the value of ; character

Comment: Thank you. What you both said is right. I performed OR operation on '1' = chr(49) and 10 = '1010' and got the answer 59, which is the ASCII value of ';'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `49 | 10 = 59` and `59` is the ASCII code of `';'`.

Answer (score 0):

It is performing the bitwise OR  operation of 49(00110001) OR 10(00001010), which is 00111011(59) , and returning the ascii value of 59, please visit the page http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html